# Why doesn't the this android layout adjust consistently on KitKat devices?

Tags: android

With the following code and layout running on a Nexus 5 in landscape mode if you tap the screen to bring up the system navigation and status bars you see the "Top" label adjust to the left to account for the size of the navigation bar that pops up on the right-hand side of the screen but the "Right" and "Bottom" labels don't move at all.  I see similar strangeness on other KitKat devices and orientations.  Either your layout should adjust for its container or it shouldn't -- but having some parts adjust while others don't is madness!

Java:

```
package com.foo.VisibilityTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getActionBar().hide();

        final View root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        root.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                root.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dapp.VisibilityTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TOP"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="BOTTOM"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```